# To add numbers and Divide it in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In the below code I have to add 4 values and divide by another value. It throws error

> must declare scalar variable

Please help me to solve the issue.

```
// Passing the values
@i_TransferQuantity float,
    @i_OnetimeCharge float,
    @i_LoadingCharge float,
    @i_UnLoadingCharge float,
    @i_FreightCharge float,
    @i_UnitPrice float

DECLARE @i_LoadingCharge, @i_UnLoadingCharge,
        @i_FreightCharge, @i_UnitPrice,
        @i_TotalUnitPrice, @i_TransferQuantity Float

SET @i_TotalUnitPrice = @i_LoadingCharge + @i_UnLoadingCharge +
                        @i_FreightCharge + @i_UnitPrice / @i_TransferQuantity
```

Comment: Do you really want to divide *only* `@i_UnitPrice` by `@i_TransferQuantity` ? Or did you want to sum those four variables and *then* divide their sum by `@i_TransferQuantity`? IN that case, you're missing some parentheses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring the same variables inside the stored procedure and they will remain uninitialized causing the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
// Passing the values
@i_TransferQuantity float,
    @i_OnetimeCharge float,
    @i_LoadingCharge float,
    @i_UnLoadingCharge float,
    @i_FreightCharge float,
    @i_UnitPrice float

DECLARE @i_LoadingCharge, @i_UnLoadingCharge,
        @i_FreightCharge, @i_UnitPrice,
        @i_TotalUnitPrice, @i_TransferQuantity Float
```

with this:

```
DECLARE @i_LoadingCharge float, @i_UnLoadingCharge float,
        @i_FreightCharge float, @i_UnitPrice float,
        @i_TotalUnitPrice float, @i_TransferQuantity float
```

You'll have to reassign new names to the incoming parameters, though, as you cannot reuse the same names twice.